# Bash Shebang scripts with a .ksh extention

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh

I have inherited shell scripts that have a bash shebang...but for some reason have a .ksh extension.

The creator of these scripts is no longer here and I cant find any reason in Google.

Why would he do this?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extension doesn't matter at all. Any or none is quite fine. What does matter is the first line of the script, which if it's a `bash` script should probably be something like this, where `/bin/bash` is the path to the shell executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

It's possible that the scripts started life as `ksh` scripts but over time the author/maintainer introduced features only available in `bash`

Comment: It should be noted that the shebang only matters when the script is invoked directly as executable. When it is given as an argument to the interpreter (eg. a shell), even the shebang doesn't matter.

Comment: In line with the comment from @Vilinkameni, sourcing a script (with `.` or `source` also ignores the shebang, actually treating it as a simple comment.

Comment: Well yes, of course